# Ensure that only certain keys are present in a document using document validator

Tags: mongodb

While inserting a document I want to check using mongodb document validation feature that all the keys present in the document are from a predefined set of keys. Assume only "a","b","c" are allowed keys and doc1 and doc2 defined below are 2 documents:

```
{
    "a": "any_value",
    "b":"any_other_value"
},
{
    "a": "any_value",
    "b": "any_other_value",
    "d": "other_value"
}
```

In this case doc1 is a valid document and doc2 is invalid.

Also, how to do this validation if in above case one more condition is added that all the keys must be present?

Note: I want to know if this can be done by Document Validation feature present in MongoDB 3.2

Comment: What is your client api? If it is nodejs, you can use moogoose framework to define the schema for a collection?

Comment: The best you can get using *document validation in MongoDB 3.2*, is require that all keys must be present, in which case "doc1" is also invalid. Is this what you want?

Comment: @user3100115 I need two validators, in first case doc1 is valid and second case is as you described, but it is necessary that no extra keys should be present

Answer (score 1):

This is possible now in Mongo 3.6 using JSON Schema validation, like so:

```
db.createCollection("myCollection", {
  validator: {
    $jsonSchema: {
      bsonType: "object",
      additionalProperties: false,
      properties: {
        _id: {
          bsonType: 'objectId',
        },
        a: {
          bsonType: "string",
        },
        b: {
          bsonType: "string",
        },
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Couple notes that might be helpful:

1. You always have to have an entry for `_id` when using `additionalProperties: false`, or every document will fail validation.
2. If you have nested objects in your schema, you need `additionalProperties: false` on every `bsonType: "object"` entry, otherwise that nested object will allow any additional properties on it.

Documentation links:

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/schema-validation/
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/jsonSchema/

Answer (score 0):

See if the following function can help you:-

```
function validateReq(obj)
{
  var prop = ['a','b','c'] //Add more property name here
  var found = false;
  for(var key in obj)
  {
    if (prop[key] && (prop[key] !== null))
    {
      found = true;
    }
    else
    {
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

Call this function like `var valid = validateReq(doc1);`, before doing insert.

If it is true, i.e. all the valid fields are present in the object you passed. Now you can do insert. Else there is some invalid field in the object.

Hope this will help!!

Answer (score 0):

With MongoDB document validation you can express the following things

- mandatory properties (document MUST have these)
- forbidden properties (document MUST NOT have these, must be specific)
- optional properties

The validator uses a query, so you can only explicitly define forbidden properties, but not limit to "only these". When searching, you'll use projection which is not possible to use in validation.

**Mandatory**:

a is mandotry

```
db.runCommand({
  collMod: "example", 
  validator:{ $and : [ {a:{$exists:1}}] }, 
  validationLevel:"strict", 
  validationAction: "error"
})
```

**Forbidden**:

d is forbidden

```
db.runCommand({
  collMod: "example", 
  validator:{ $and : [ {b:{$exists:0}}] }, 
  validationLevel:"strict", 
  validationAction: "error"
})
```

**Optional**:
a is mandatory
b is optional

```
db.runCommand({
  collMod: "example", 
  validator:{ 
   $and : [ 
     {a:{$exists:1}},  //mandatory
     {d:{$exists:0}},  //forbidden
     {$or:[
      {b:{$exists:1}}, //optional
      {c:{$exists:1}}]} ] }, 
  validationLevel:"strict", 
  validationAction: "error"
 })
```

This will accept these documents

- {a:1}
- {a:1, b:1}
- {a:1, c:1}
- {a:1, b:1, c:1}
- {a:1, b:1, e:1} -> e is allowed because a and b fullfill validation

These documents are not accepted

- {a:1, d:1} -> d is forbidden
- {a:1, e:1} -> b or c is not satisfied
- {a:1, b:1, d:1} -> d is forbidden

Comment: The problem is there are infinite keys so I was asking that is there any way to define that everything except the defined keys are forbidden

Comment: No, that's not possible with document validation (and this is probably the anwser for your question.)

Answer (score 0):

Actually it's not possible to allow only a given fields in the document. But you can require that certain fields must be present using the [document validation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document-validation/) feature new in MongoDB 3.2 and the [`$and`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/and/) like this:

```
db.createCollection( "collection", 
   { "validator": { 
       "$and": [         
           { "a": { "$exists": true } },         
           { "b": { "$exists": true } }, 
           { "c": { "$exists": true } } 
       ]
    }}
)
```

Also, you can't insert or update documents that don't fulfill your validation criteria unless you set  `validationLevel: "moderate"`.

I think it would be good if MongoDB allow default values to be set for new documents. Now there is an assigned issue  for new feature [SERVER-24430](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-24430).

Comment: but in this case if any document have a key other than a,b,c then also it validates the document which is not desired

Comment: @tpnsharma This is not possible you will need to use a third party tools for this.